# How to pass an object as props to a child Functional Component in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code with a config file `testType`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from "./components/Select/Select";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    testType : [
      {value : "test1", name : "Test1"},
      {value : "test2", name : "Test2"},
    ]
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
              <Select {...this.state.testType}/>
              <Select {...this.state.testType}/>
            </>
            );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Which I use to pass as props to a Select Component, below is the code for it `Select.js` :

```
import React from "react";
const selectoption = (props) => (
<select className="custom-select">
    <option value={props.value}>{props.name}</option>
</select>
);

export default selectoption;
```

But it does not work, I don't see the `props` test1 and test2 in the select element.

Comment: Are you mixing up `Test` and `Select`? I think you've included select but your first code block uses test

Comment: Your passing testType which is an array you need to map through it.

Comment: No I just want to use Select

Comment: You seem to be spreading the whole array to each of two `Test` components, that doesn't make sense - did you want to render one `Test` for each item in the array? See e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html.

Comment: No I really want to spread the whole array to each of the two Select components. Because in the future I want to be able to use different arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are doing well.
I've just read your descriptions carefully.
Data you have passed through props is an array of objects.
So in the selectoption components the "prop" is an array of objects.
You cannot find "value" and "name" of this props.
You must map this array to get data of each options.

Or you can change the code like this.

<Select {...this.state.testType[0]}/>

<Select {...this.state.testType[1]}/>

Comment: The problem is that I have in the first select `test1` and in the second `test2` whereas I want to have `test1` and `test2` in both the 2 selects.

Comment: You can change the code of selectoption component like this.


const selectoption= ({ list }) => (
  <select className="custom-select">
    {list.map(option => (
      <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>
    ))}
  </select>
);

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is when you are doing `<Select {...this.state.testType}/>` the below is the data that will be received as `prop` in the `Select` component. So basically the array is getting converted to below format in the `Select` component.

```json
{
  "0": {
    "value": "test1",
    "name": "Test1"
  },
  "1": {
    "value": "test2",
    "name": "Test2"
  }
}
```

So, instead of spreading it that way if it's being passed as `list={[...this.state.testType]}` then the passed array can be accessed in `Select` component as `props.list` or in the component itself it can be spread like `const Select = ({ list }) => {...}`. The passed `list` can be looped through using `Array.map` and then render all the options.

```js
const { Component, Fragment } = React;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    testType: [
      { value: "test1", name: "Test1" },
      { value: "test2", name: "Test2" }
    ]
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Select list={[...this.state.testType]} />
        <Select list={[...this.state.testType]} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const Select = ({ list }) => (
  <select className="custom-select">
    {list.map(option => (
      <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>
    ))}
  </select>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

For more info about rendering list elements in React please [refer here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your vote.
I am a dedicated and reliable Full-Stack Developer with over 10 years of experience in Web Development.
I have strong skills and experience with React,Vue,Angular Frontend Development and Backend Development with RESTful APIs using Node.js and Laravel.
I can help you with my strong development skills.
You will be happy with my quality of code and fast delivery.
I am full time available and I can overlap at least 8 hrs a day in your timezone.